# If I want to create a Blockchain Explorer, would be enough just use Infura? Or is it essential to run a full node?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, infura, explorers

I want to create a Blockchain Explorer and I am wondering if using Infura for that would be enough, or if it would be necessary to run a private node on Ethereum.

I am not sure about Infura speed to show the data and how it would behave with a lot of users making requests at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need your own archive node, if you want as much information as posible of Ethereum blockchain state. As you will know there are three types of nodes in Ethereum:

1. Full node
2. Light node
3. Archive node

**Full node** [From Ethereum Documentation](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/nodes-and-clients/#full-node)

- Stores full blockchain data.
- Participates in block validation, verifies all blocks and states.
- All states can be derived from a full node.
- Serves the network and provides data on request.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to run your own node in order to get enough data to create a block explorer.

With Infura (and any other node provider), you will be limited by both number of calls and archival data.